# Is ΩΣ in {simplicial commutative monoids} group completion?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ct.category-theory

Let C be the model category of simplicial commutative monoids (with underlying weak equivalences and fibrations), or equivalently the (∞,1)-category P<sub>Σ</sub>(T<sup>op</sup>), where T is the Lawvere theory for commutative monoids.  In C, as in any pointed (∞,1)-category with finite limits and colimits, we can define adjoint functors Σ<sub>C</sub> and Ω<sub>C</sub> as Σ<sub>C</sub>X = hocolim [• ← X → •] and Ω<sub>C</sub>X = holim [• → X ← •].

The category CommMon of commutative monoids sits inside C as a full subcategory (as the constant objects, or the objectwise-discrete presheaves).  Consider the two functors CommMon → C given by sending M to Ω<sub>C</sub>Σ<sub>C</sub>M and to the group completion of M, respectively.  Is there a natural equivalence between these functors?

(This question is closely related to [Chris's question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430/homological-algebra-for-commutative-monoids).  A thorough answer to that question would probably yield this immediately.)

Comment: This doesn't work at the level of $\pi_0$.  If $M$ is such that $\pi_0 M$ is say the natural numbers you want its group completion to satisfy $\pi_0$ is the integers, right?  But $\pi_0 \Omega \Sigma$ of any topological monoid equivalent to the naturals should be huge, a free group on infinitely many generators.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: The underlying space of $\Sigma M$ won't be the suspension of the underlying space of $M$, because the forgetful functor from C to Spaces doesn't commute with colimits.  For instance, if I replaced "commutative monoids" with "abelian groups", then C would be the category of nonnegatively-graded chain complexes, $\Sigma$ would be a shift so that $(\Sigma X)_n = X_{n-1}$, $\Omega$ would be a shift in the other direction, and $\Omega \Sigma$ would be the identity functor.

Comment: So "$\Sigma M$" is really a model for the classifying space $BM$?  So you are really asking: what does $BM$ of a discrete commutative monoid $M$ look like?  In particular, does it have non-trivial homotopy groups in dimensions greater than $1$?  (That's how I read your question, anyway.)

Comment: That's part of my question, and the other part is to identify $\Sigma_C M$ with $BM$ (is that obvious?  I don't see it right away.)  I tried to clarify exactly what my notation was intended to mean.

Comment: I think that's basically an equivalent question; Quillen ("On the group completion of a simplicial monoid") showed that the homotopy group completion $\Omega BM$ is weakly equivalent to levelwise group completion for cofibrant objects.  So I think identifying $\Sigma_C M$ with $BM$ is the key issue.  My best guess is to show it's equivalent for objects that are free on a simplicial set (since the free functor commutes with suspension) and then bootstrap it up to cofibrant objects using pushout diagrams.

Comment: Well, simplicial commutative monoids is cotensored over pointed simplicial sets.  If I use this to define $\Sigma_C M$ to mean $(\Delta^1/\partial \Delta^1)\otimes M$, then I think this is *exactly* a model for $BM$, using the fact that finite comproducts of commutative monoids are set theoretic products.  And my "cotensor suspension" is really the same as your "pushout suspension", since $C$ is a proper simplicial model category.  Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: @Charles: Oh yes, thanks!  That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think an answer is given by the arguments that Segal gives in Section 4 of his paper on "Categories and Cohomology Theories" (aka, the $\Gamma$-space paper), in Topology, v.13.  I'll try to sketch the main idea, translated into the context of simplicial commutative monoids.  I'll show that if $M$ is a discrete simplicial commutative monoid, then it's group completion is homotopically discrete; according to the comments, this should answer the question.

Given a commutative monoid $M$, we can define a simplicial commuative monoid $M'$ as the nerve of the category whose objects are $(m_1,m_2)\in M\times M$, and where morphisms $(m_1,m_2)\to (m_1',m_2')$ are $m\in M$ such that $m_im=m_i'$.  We can prolong this to a functor on simplicial commutative monoids.

Let $H=H_*|M|=H_*(|M|,F)$ (the homology of the geometric realization of $M$, with coefficients in some field $F$), viewed as a commutative ring under the pontryagin product.  Then Segal shows that $H_*|M'|\approx H[\pi^{-1}]$, where $\pi$ denotes the image of $\pi_0|M|$ in $H_0|M]$.  His proof amounts to computing the homology spectral sequence for a simplicial space whose realization is $M'$, and whose $E_2$-term is $\mathrm{Tor}_i^H(H\otimes H,F)$, and observing that the higher tor-groups vanish.

This means that if $M$ is discrete, then $H_*|M'|$ is concentrated in degree $0$.  Since $|M'|$ is a grouplike commutative monoid, the Hurewicz theorem should tell us that $|M'|$ is weakly equivalent to a discrete space, namely the group completion of the monoid $M$.

Segal goes on to show that $BM\to BM'$ is a weak equivalence, using the above homology calculation and another spectral sequence.  Since $M'$ is weakly equivalent to a group, $\Omega BM\approx \Omega BM'\approx M'$.