# Whitehead Products without Base Points?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $(X, x_0)$ be a pointed space. Then we can define the homotopy groups $\pi_i(X, x_0)$ for $i \geq 1$. They are abelian groups for $i \geq 2$. It is well-known that the fundamental group $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ acts on each of the higher groups $\pi_i(X, x_0)$, and that this action generalizes to the [Whitehead Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product) which are maps

$$ \pi_p(X, x_0) \times \pi_q(X, x_0) \to \pi_{p+q -1}(X, x_0).$$

The details are given in the wikipedia article I linked to above. Together the Whitehead products turn the graded group $\pi_*(X, x_0)$ (for $* > 0$) into a graded (quasi-) Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$, where the grading is shifted so that $\pi_i(X, x_0)$ is in degree $(i-1)$. Well, it is a little funny since the bottom group is not necessarily abelian.

> This is all well and good, but what if we don't want to pick base points? Is there a similar algebraic gadget in that situation?

If we don't pick base points, then it seems natural to consider the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_1(X)$. Then the different homotopy groups of $X$ at different base points can be assembled into local systems on $X$. That is for each $i \geq 2$ we have a functor,

$$\pi_i: \Pi_1 X \to AB$$

where $AB$ is the category of abelian groups. This already incorporates the action of $\pi_1$ on the higher homotopy groups but does it in a way which doesn't depend on the choice of base point.

> Question: Can we enhance these local systems with a structure which generalizes the Whitehead product, and if so what precisely is this extra structure?

Comment:  What's wrong with just taking all higher homotopy groups as a functor $\oplus_{k>1}\pi_k:\Pi_1(X)\to $graded Lie algebras with $\pi_1$ actions? As you note, you can separate out the $\pi_1$ part.


Also, could you explain why you don't want to pick base points? Whitehead products are obscure and tricky to calculate (except as commutators on $\pi_1$), and I'm curious about what context you are thinking about.


Comment: That was my first guess too. I played around with that a little, and the problem is that it didn't seem to give a functor to graded Lie algebras. The paths act by something which is more like a derivation. You can see this by looking at how $\pi_1$ acts. It acts by the Lie bracket [x,-]. I'm hoping someone who is more familiar with Whitehead product or graded Lie algebras will know what this structure is.  

Comment: My motivation for this comes from trying to follow up on my previous MO questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14266/a-peculiar-model-structure-on-simplicial-sets and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/430/homological-algebra-for-commutative-monoids . Basically those questions led me to try to understand the homotopy of topological commutative monoids and I need a sufficiently rich algebraic invariant to help with this. It seems very important in that world that you can't simply reduce a single component and a single base point. This question is a step towards finding that invariant. 

Comment: Chris, are you sure you that Paul's suggestion doesn't work? The action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_k$ is *not* by the Lie bracket: If $g \in pi_1$ and $m \in \pi_k$, then (up to a sign) $[g,m] = gm - m$.  (For instance, the usual action of $\pi_1$ on itself is by conjugation so this recovers $[g,h]=g h g^{-1} h^{-1}$.)  Using this last formula, I think one gets that the Whitehead algebra *is* a Lie algebra in $\pi_1$-modules.

Comment: Rather, the formula shows that bracketing with elements of $\pi_1$ gives $\pi_1$-module morphisms.  I think I have a conceptual reason why things should work, so I'll post that in an answer.

Comment: Did you look at how Sullivan handled this when he did rational homotopy theory for non-simply connected spaces? That would correspond to the (easier) case of $\pi_k\otimes Q$. 

I   think of such things in terms of universal covers rather than groupoids and/or l.c. sheaves, and let the covering transformations deal with the action of $\pi_1$.  What happens if you consider the homotopy groups of the universal cover based at different points? you should get another description since the homotopy groups of a cover coincide with the base, and since Whitehead products are preserved by homeos.

Comment: @Paul & Anatoly: You are right. I made a sloppy mistake thinking the action of $\pi_1$ was the same as the Lie bracket. You can see that it is not if you look carefully at the definition of the bracket. You can also see that it is indeed functorial as you suggest. 

Using universal covers doesn't quite work because the universal cover is only functorial after picking a base point (you can see that from the constructions of it).  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I posted in my comment, I think Paul's suggestion does work.  Here's a (sloppy) description of how I think things will work:

The local systems you describe can be obtained, by passing to homotopy groups, from a "local system of loop spaces" $$ \Omega: \Pi_{\leq \infty} X \to \Omega\mathbf{Spaces}$$ 
One can imagine that this corresponds under the Grothendieck construction to the free loop-space fibration $\Omega X \to LX \to X$.  Alternatively, if we fix a basepoint and identify $X = BG$ for a simplicial group $G$, then this is just encoding the simplicial conjugation action of $G$ on itself.

Rather than think about (strangely-graded) Whitehead products, I prefer to think about (reasonably graded) Samelson products: We think of the structure (Whitehead product) on $\pi_{*+1} X $ as really being a structure (Samelson product) on $\pi_{*} \Omega X$.  I claim that Samelson products give a functor
$$ \pi_*: \Omega\mathbf{Spaces} \to \mathbf{grqLie} $$ so that composing with the above gives our desired "local system of graded (quasi-)Lie algebras".

For convenience, I'll replace loop spaces with (strict) simplicial groups.  Then, the Samelson product comes from noticing that the commutator map $[,]: G^2 \to G$ is trivial if one of the factors is the identity, and so factors through a pointed map $[,]: G \wedge G \to G$.  This pointed map goes on to induce the (quasi-)Lie structure on homotopy.  A group homomorphism $H \to G$ preserves commutators and identities, and so induces a map $H \wedge H \to G \wedge G$ compatible with the brackets, so that this construction is indeed functorial.