# A generalization of cochain complex: quasi-cochain complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology

It appears that we can generalize cochain complex to quasi-cochain complex, that still allow us to define cohomology.

**Definition:**
A quasi-cochain complex is a sequence of commutative monoids $M_n$ connected
by monoid-homomorphisms $d_n$:
\begin{align}
\cdots \overset{d_{n-1}}{\rightarrow}
  M_n
\overset{d_n}{\rightarrow}
  M_{n+1}
\overset{d_{n+1}}{\rightarrow}
  M_{n+2}
\overset{d_{n+2}}{\rightarrow} \cdots ,
\end{align}
such that
$d_{n+1}d_n$ maps  $M_n$ to $0_{n+2}$ (the identity in $M_{n+2}$), 
the subset of $M_n$, $A_n=\{a_n|d_n(a_n)=0,a_n\in M_n\}$
is an Abelian group, --Edit-- and the Img$(d_n)$ is also an Abelian group.

In the quasi-cochain complex, we can define the cohomology classes
since both $\text{Ker}(d_n)$ and $\text{Img}(d_{n-1})$ are Abelian groups:
$H^n=\text{Ker}(d_n)/\text{Img}(d_{n-1})$.

I wonder

(1) if the above definition is OK

(2) Has any one studied such a quasi-cochain complex.

Comment: I don't see why the image should be an abelian group. Also, a map between different monoids cannot be the identity, I bet you mean zero.

Comment: Since $d_{n+1}d_n$ maps $M_n$ to the identity of $M_{n+2}$, img$(d_n)$ is a subset of ker$(d_{n+1})$. ker$(d_{n+1})$ is an Abelian group, and thus img$(d_n)$ is an Abelian subgroup.

Comment: So $\mathbb N$ is an abelian subgroup of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I see your point. But here we assume img$(d_n)$ to be an Abelian group. I modified my question to add this assumption.

Comment: I don't see the assumption in your question.

Comment: BTW, if you assume that both kernels and images are groups then so are all the monoids, so you end up with a chain complex.

Comment: **both kernels and images of $d_n$ are groups implies that all the monoids $M_n$ are groups.** This will be a great result for me. I can indeed show that both kernels and images are groups and I want to get the usual chain complex. But is the above statement really true? How to prove it? It is not obvious to me. (I am a physicist.)

Comment: A proof is given below. I wish that I had the intuition to see the theorem: if the kernel and the image have a property, then the original set also has the property

Comment: You should look at the papers of Alex Patchkoria listed on MathSciNet for another approach to using abelian modules: he uses abelian semimodules.  I might say more later.

Comment: @Ronnie I am also interested in a generalization of cochain complex where $M_n$ are commutative monoids (without the condition that kernels and images of $d_n$ are Abelian groups). This question is asked in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/430/homological-algebra-for-commutative-monoids. But I did find simple reviews there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kong Liang told me a proof for
the statement **if both kernels and images of $d_n$ are Abelian groups then all the monoids $M_n$ are Abelian groups**.

Let  $f: A \to B$ be a surjective morphism between two commutative monoids.
Surjectivity means  $B =$ Img$(f)$.
Assume that Ker$(f)$ is an Abelian group and $B =$ Img$(f)$ is an Abelian group.

Then $A$ is automatically an Abelian group.

Proof:

1. it is enough to show that any element $a$ in $A$ has a right inverse $a'$,
   i.e.  $a a' = 1$. (by the commutativity,  $a' a = a a' = 1$.)
   Notice that if such $a'$ exists, it must be unique. Otherwise,
   let $a'$ and $a''$ be such that     $a a' =1 = a a''$.
   Then we have $a' = a' a a'' = a''$  (use commutativity)
2. For any $a$ in $A$, let $b$ be the inverse of $f( a )$
   and let $c$ be an element in $A$ such that $f( c ) = b$. Then we have
   $f(a c) = f( a ) f( c ) = f( a ) b =1$.
   Therefore, $a c$ is in the Ker$(f)$. Since Ker$(f)$ is an Abelian group,
   there is an element $d \in A$ such that $acd = 1$.
   Hence $cd$ is the right inverse of $a$.

Therefore the quasi-cochain complex is the usual cochain complex, and there is a lot of work on cochain complex, as well as a lot of theorems. :-)
Thanks, @ Fernando Muro !

Comment: You're welcome. I'd say this is rather elementary from a mathematical point of view, though.

Comment: Indeed, it is  elementary. But the result is very important to me.