# Chain homotopy of non-abelian category

Tags: homological-algebra

How can one define the chain homotopy in non-abelian category? (The category I have in mind is the category of chain complexes of monoids.)

Comment: The notion of chain homotopy is induced by an "algebraic" interval, namely the chain complex corresponding to the simplicial complex $\Delta^1$. I don't see how to build that chain complex without using subtraction.

Comment: Replace it with simplicial homotopy of maps between simplicial objects. (There's no reason, from the perspective of homotopical algebra, to work in the category of chain complexes of monoids, as the Dold-Kan theorem fails in this setting.)

Comment: For *commutative* simplicial monoids one may add up separately odd-numbered and even-numbered face operators to obtain a globular structure (something like chain complex with parallel pairs of boundary operators). See e. g. [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610117.pdf).

I don't know if something similar can be done in the noncommutative case...

Comment: This mathoverflow thread might be useful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/430/homological-algebra-for-commutative-monoids